# How to set text a select html with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

i founded more example about this, but when i try , it's not work.

```js
$(window).load(function () {
$("#country").html('Please select in here');
});
```

```html
<select id="country">
<option value="None">-- Select --</option>
<option value="China">China</option>
<option value="United State">United State</option>
<option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
</select>
```

Please see it and tell me "Why it's not working?".Thank guys

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: Dear @Vohuman, I don't understand , please detail it , I want when load , text of select is : Please select in here  such as `$("#country").html('Please select in here');`.

Comment: you did not include jquery script

Comment: Dear @Heyyou , not have a textbox ?

Comment: Do you want to replace the text content of the first `option`?

Comment: Dear @Pekka , no no , i have used jquery

Comment: @BrianCrist i see a comment saying $ is not defined then some other function is using $

Comment: @Vohuman , No , I want to show text of select in the first time. Not change content of the first .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you want, but if you want to add another option just append/prepend new option into select like so:

```js
$(window).load(function () {
$("#country").prepend('<option value="" selected>Please select in here</option>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country">
<option value="None">-- Select --</option>
<option value="China">China</option>
<option value="United State">United State</option>
<option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yub , It's working for me , When load , we use `prepend` as @Norlihazmey Ghazali to say.

Answer (score 4):

It's impractical to replace the whole content between `<select id="country">` and `</select>` with `'Please select in here'` ? If you just want to replace the first option's content, then try this.

```js
$(window).load(function () {  
  //$("#country").html('Please select in here');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  //$("#country").html('Please select in here');
  $("#country").find("option:first-child").html('Please select in here');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country">
<option value="None">-- Select --</option>
<option value="China">China</option>
<option value="United State">United State</option>
<option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Dear @UKA , it's look well.

Answer (score 1):

```html
Please select in here:
<select id="country">
<option value="None">-- Select --</option>
<option value="China">China</option>
<option value="United State">United State</option>
<option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
</select>
```

You can't add text in the select. You need to add in front of it.

If you really want to add the text after load, put one more div in front of the select to control

Answer (score 1):

Bit confuse what you trying to achieve

To Pre append

```
$('#country').prepend('<option>Please select in here</option>');
```

To dynamically Select:

```
$('#country').val("None")
```

Add new Option:

```
$('#country').append(new Option('Foo', true));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but if you just want to change the default text, you probably are looking for something like this:

```
<select id="country">
    <option value="None" selected>Please select in here</option> <!-- set the default selection -->
    <option value="China">China</option>
    <option value="United State">United State</option>
    <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
</select>
```

and then the JS to set a new value would be:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#country").val('China');
});
```